# FatalErrorException: Call to undefined function link_to_route()

Tags: php, laravel

I am a new user of Laravel, I'm just studying and practising, however I have the error below when I run my code

> FatalErrorException in 91c2dfaa1622335ef6854835b55abc4fabeefb25.php line 33:
>   Call to undefined function link_to_route()

Below is my controller

```
Route::get('/',  [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@home'
]);

route::group(['prefix'=>'auth'], function(){

    route::get('register', [
        'as' => 'get_register',
        'uses' => 'Auth/RegisterController@getRegister'
        ]);

    route::post('register', [
        'as' => 'post_register',
        'uses' => 'Auth/RegisterController@register'
        ]);
});
```

My tutorial put the controller like the one below

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('register',[
        'as' => 'get_register',
        'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'
        ]);
    Route::post('register',[
        'as' => 'post_register',
        'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'
        ]);
});
```

But inside Auth folder, I don't have `authcontroller`, I only have `registercontroller`. and this is my link in my navigation

```
<li>{!! link_to_route('get_register','Register')!!}</li>
```

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: use route('get_register'); instead

Answer (score 3):

`link_to_route` comes from the HTML/Form Builder package, which is not part of Laravel since version 5.0. If you are on Laravel 5.0 you can use `illuminate/html` or `laravelcollective/html`. For > 5.0 you would need `laravelcollective/html`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code need to update like:

```
<li>{!! link_to_route('get_register','Register')!!}</li>
```

To

```
<a href="{{ url('register') }}">Register</a>
```

**OR**

You need to install a package named `"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"`

In your *composer.json* file, Write this line

```
"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
```

Then open *config/app.php* file, In provider array,Write this line:-

```
'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

Next, add these lines to the 'aliases' array:

```
'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',

   'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Thanks, this works for me  <a href="{{ url('register') }}">Register</a>

Comment: Thanks, now i have one more error, the link throw Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
1/1NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179:                                             below is my controller   Route::group(['prefix'=>'auth'], function(){

 Route::get('register', [
        'as' => 'get_register',
        'uses' => 'Auth/RegisterController@RegistersUsers'
  ]);
 Route::post('register', [
        'as' => 'post_register',
        'uses' => 'Auth/RegisterController@register'
  ]);
});     my link     <a href="{{ url('register') }}">Register</a>

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 use the [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route) helper instead of `link_to_route()`:

```
{!! route('get_register') !!}
```